# Deploying a Rails 3.1 app on Heroku error : Could not find libv8-3.3.10.3 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundle

I have troubles to push my rails app on heroku. In my local server, I have no problem to execute "bundle install" and my app works well. 
When I run "git push heroku master", I have this error

```
Could not find libv8-3.3.10.3 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

My local config is :
 - Mac OS Lion
 - Rails 3.1.0
 - Ruby 1.9.2

My heroku stack is Cedar.

My Gemfile is :

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  # gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.7.0", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.6.7", :group => :test
gem "mongoid-rspec", ">= 1.4.4", :group => :test
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 1.3.0", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.1.1", :group => :test
gem "capybara", ">= 1.1.1", :group => :test
gem "launchy", ">= 2.0.5", :group => :test
gem "bson_ext", ">= 1.3.0"
gem "mongoid", ">= 2.0.1"
gem "omniauth", ">= 0.3.0"
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "devise", ">= 1.4.7"
gem "fb_graph", ">= 2.2.3"
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'thin'
gem 'heroku'
```

In my Gemfile.lock in local, I have libv8 (3.3.10.4) installed.

I tried "bundle update", I tried add "libv8" in my Gemfile. Nothing works. 
Does anyone have an idea ?

UPDATE :

My Gemfile.lock contains libv8 twice :

```
GEM
  specs
    ...
    libv8 (3.3.10.4)
    ...
    therubyracer (0.9.9)
      libv8 (~> 3.3.10)
    ...
```

There is nothing in "DEPENDENCIES" part of Gemfile.lock :

```
DEPENDENCIES
  bson_ext (>= 1.3.0)
  capybara (>= 1.1.1)
  chronic
  coffee-rails (~> 3.1.0)
  cucumber-rails (>= 1.1.1)
  database_cleaner (>= 0.6.7)
  devise (>= 1.4.7)
  factory_girl_rails (>= 1.3.0)
  fb_graph (>= 2.2.3)
  heroku
  jquery-rails
  launchy (>= 2.0.5)
  less-rails-bootstrap
  mongoid (>= 2.0.1)
  mongoid-rspec (>= 1.4.4)
  omniauth (>= 0.3.0)
  omniauth-facebook
  rails (= 3.1.0)
  rspec-rails (>= 2.7.0)
  thin
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Result of "gem list libv8"

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-darwin-11)
```

Result of "gem environment"

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Is your application using the correct stack for 3.1 - ie, Cedar?

Comment: yes, I use cedar stack on heroku. I followed this guide : http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html

Comment: Please post all Gemfile.lock lines which include `libv8` so we can see all the dependencies, it should be shown at least twice and possibly more. Please post result of `gem list libv8` so we can see exactly what gems are installed. Please post result of `gem environment` so we can see where your gems are installed locally.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've just updated my question with the results you're asking.

Comment: I had issues before with using the rubyracer runtime for coffeescript compilation. I have two heroku 3.1 apps at the moment, neither of them do i specify the run time. http://pastie.org/3243364 http://pastie.org/3243366. Looking at the lockfile, it's using execjs

Comment: In fact (if i understand well), I do not specify the rubyracer in my Gemfile, but it appears on my lockfile. Normal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clean out your bundle and ensure that therubyracer is gone:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting

```
bundle clean
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact it was not enough. I had to reinitialize git and commit everything again. But I think it helped me, so I validate your answer. Problem solved. :)